# Select multiple id's with almost same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have of form automatically generated with js from a provider that i unfortunately can't change...

But i would like to know if there's only solution that allows me to select all id's which begin by the same string like : easi_fielddiv_LastName, easi_fielddiv_FirstName, easi_fielddiv_Email etc... because the idea is to select all of them and apply them a class to be more eficient with my css.

Here's the form code :

```
<div id="easiformarea">
   <form name="easiform" id="easiform" class="easiform">
      <div id="easi_fielddiv_Salutation">
         <span id="easi_labelspan_Salutation"><label id="easi_fieldlabel_Salutation">Civilité</label></span>
         <span id="easi_fieldspan_Salutation">
            <select id="fld_Salutation" name="fld_Salutation" label="Civilité" mandatory="true">
               <option value="" label=""></option>
               <option value="Mme" label="Madame">Madame</option>
               <option value="Mlle." label="Mademoiselle">Mademoiselle</option>
               <option value="Mr" label="Monsieur">Monsieur</option>
            </select>
         </span>
         <span id="easi_fielmandatoryspan_Salutation" class="mandatory"> * </span>
      </div>
      <div id="easi_fielddiv_LastName"><span id="easi_labelspan_LastName"><label id="easi_fieldlabel_LastName">Nom</label></span><span id="easi_fieldspan_LastName"><input id="fld_LastName" type="text" name="fld_LastName" label="Nom" mandatory="true"></span><span id="easi_fielmandatoryspan_LastName" class="mandatory"> * </span></div>
      <div id="easi_fielddiv_FirstName"><span id="easi_labelspan_FirstName"><label id="easi_fieldlabel_FirstName">Prénom</label></span><span id="easi_fieldspan_FirstName"><input id="fld_FirstName" type="text" name="fld_FirstName" label="Prénom" mandatory="true"></span><span id="easi_fielmandatoryspan_FirstName" class="mandatory"> * </span></div>
      <div id="easi_fielddiv_Email"><span id="easi_labelspan_Email"><label id="easi_fieldlabel_Email">Email</label></span><span id="easi_fieldspan_Email"><input id="fld_Email" type="text" name="fld_Email" label="Email" mandatory="true"></span><span id="easi_fielmandatoryspan_Email" class="mandatory"> * </span></div>
      <div id="easi_fielddiv_OfficePhoneNumber"><span id="easi_labelspan_OfficePhoneNumber"><label id="easi_fieldlabel_OfficePhoneNumber">Téléphone</label></span><span id="easi_fieldspan_OfficePhoneNumber"><input id="fld_OfficePhoneNumber" type="text" name="fld_OfficePhoneNumber" label="Téléphone" mandatory="false"></span></div>
      <div id="easi_fielddiv_CS_Booking"><span id="easi_labelspan_CS_Booking"><label id="easi_fieldlabel_CS_Booking">Booking</label></span><span id="easi_fieldspan_CS_Booking"><input id="fld_CS_Booking" type="text" name="fld_CS_Booking" label="Booking" mandatory="false"></span></div>
      <div id="easi_fielddiv_CS_Subject">
         <span id="easi_labelspan_CS_Subject"><label id="easi_fieldlabel_CS_Subject">Sujet</label></span>
         <span id="easi_fieldspan_CS_Subject">
            <select id="fld_CS_Subject" name="fld_CS_Subject" label="Sujet" mandatory="true">
               <option value="" label=""></option>
               <option value="1" label="Je veux annuler mon vol">Je veux annuler mon vol</option>
            </select>
         </span>
         <span id="easi_fielmandatoryspan_CS_Subject" class="mandatory"> * </span>
      </div>
      <div id="easi_fielddiv_CS_SubSubject">
         <span id="easi_labelspan_CS_SubSubject"><label id="easi_fieldlabel_CS_SubSubject">Sous-sujet</label></span>
         <span id="easi_fieldspan_CS_SubSubject">
            <select id="fld_CS_SubSubject" name="fld_CS_SubSubject" label="Sous-sujet" mandatory="true">
               <option value="" label=""></option>
            </select>
         </span>
         <span id="easi_fielmandatoryspan_CS_SubSubject" class="mandatory"> * </span>
      </div>
      <div id="easi_fielddiv_Description"><span id="easi_labelspan_Description"><label id="easi_fieldlabel_Description">Description</label></span><span id="easi_fieldspan_Description"><textarea id="fld_Description" name="fld_Description" label="Description" mandatory="false"></textarea></span></div>
      <div id="easi_fielddiv_AttachedFiles">
         <span id="easi_labelspan_AttachedFiles"><label id="easi_fieldlabel_AttachedFiles">Pièces jointes</label></span>
         <span id="easi_fieldspan_AttachedFiles">
            <div id="fld_AttachedFilesarea"> <input id="fld_AttachedFiles" type="file" name="fld_AttachedFiles" label="Pièces jointes" mandatory="false" multiple=""></div>
         </span>
      </div>
      <span class="easiformmessages" id="easiformmessages"></span>
   </form>
   <div class="mandatoryfieldmention" id="mandatoryfieldmention">* champs obligatoires</div>
   <div class="additionnalInformation" id="additionnalInformation">Un numéro de dossier renseigné est une demande traitée plus rapidement!</div>
   <button id="validatebutton" class="validatebutton" onclick="myformbuilder.valideasiform();">Envoyer</button>
</div>
```

I tried to select element by tag name on inputs and then get the `parent().parent()` to reach the id's that interest me but it doesn't seem to work...

So any help is appreciated !!! Thanks :)

Comment: `$( "[id^='easi_']" )` all id beginning with `easi_`

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this (jQuery needed)

```
  $('*[id^="easi_fielddiv"]');
```

This will select all element (*) that start (^) with 'easy_fielddiv'

Comment: Thank you so much it's exactly what i needed !!!! :)